# Div tag not displaying because height is 0

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I recently bought a template and trying to integrate it in a Rails app. 
After adding the html the div (**training-posts-about-img**) on left is displayed but the one on right (**about-training-slider-wrapper**) is not.

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="width-container">
        <div id="training-posts-about" class="about-widget-container">      
            <div class="training-posts-about-img">
                <img src="images/demo/trainer-2.jpg" alt="pro-trainer">
            </div>
            <div class="about-training-slider-wrapper">
                <div class="flexslider about-trainers-slider fiziko-slider-pro">
                    <ul class="slides">                         
                        <li>
                            <div class="about-slider-container">
                                <h2 class="home-widget">We believe in...</h2>
                                <p class="home-widget-caption">Cras libero ante, tincidunt nec ornare vitae, dignissim vel neque. </p>
                                <p class="home-widget-description">Suspendisse egestas semper t. </p>
                                <a class="ls-sc-button default">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="about-slider-container">
                                <h2 class="home-widget">A message from our staff</h2>
                                <p class="home-widget-caption">Cras libero ante, tincidunt nec ornare vitae, dignissim vel neque. </p>
                                <p class="home-widget-description"> id vestibulum massa nunc nec enim. Cras. </p>
                                <a class="ls-sc-button default">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>                           
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>        
    </div><!-- close .width-container -->   
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div><!-- close #main -->
```

[Here is the page link, the first div with image 592X586](https://nameless-dawn-8962.herokuapp.com/about)

the css :

```
#training-posts-about h2.home-widget {
text-align: left;
}
.training-posts-about-img {width: 44%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;}
.training-posts-about-img img {margin: -85px 0px -90px -40px;}
.about-training-slider-wrapper {width: 55%;float: right;}

 #training-posts-about .home-widget-caption {margin-left: 0px; margin- bottom: 25px;}
#training-posts-about .home-widget-description {font-size: 14px;}
```

I tried adding **overflow: hidden** to **width-container** but that wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

there is a display none on the li. here's the css causing the issue:

```
.flexslider .slides>li {
    display: none;
}
```

in your css you could add:

```
.flexslider .slides>li {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read all of your code but I see you are using `float`. By using `float` you are essentially removing the height of the parent container if there's nothing else inside that isn't floated.